# Did something happen to "Start A Bounty"?

Tags: support, status-completed, bounty

Is it my imagination or could you Start a Bounty on someone else's question?  I've finally found a question that I'm willing to give some rep to, but I cannot find the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "start a bounty" link displayed on eligible questions. The criteria for bounties, listed in the [FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq), are as follows:

- Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.
- Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.
- There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time.
- Once initiated, the bounty period lasts 7 days.
- After starting a bounty, you must wait 1 day before awarding it.
- If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

Your question is probably not meeting the first criteria. Without knowing the question though, I can't tell you for sure.

In case it's not clear, the start bounty link is shown here at the bottom, just below the `add comment` link :

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  The question isn't old enough http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11977/kids-lunch-box-suggestion-for-fruit-smoothie-packaging

Comment: Am I mis-reading, or was the bounty i put up on [Russian Chili](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/what-would-make-this-chili-recipe-to-be-russian-chili/10740#10740) never awarded to Cold Oatmeal? I don't think i got a +100 refund or anything like that, but the question doesn't seem to indicate (maybe a browser issue; im on IE 7 at work) a +100 bounty for him (I let the 7 day auto-award do its thing since i had an answer in there).